# Compile(Ivy) and build (Bazel) with Angular

Tags: angular, bazel, angular-ivy, angular9

I'm new into Angular and I'm trying to understand what's coming with Angular 9. I know Ivy is the new view engine and compiles our code  and Bazel builds it, but does Bazel compiles it too? or Ivy does it, then Bazel does the build? I'm confused on this part, Also does Bazel takes place during AOT or not?

Comment: It may take some reading but the answer should be in here https://angular.io/docs

Comment: To learn more about Bazel:
https://blog.bitsrc.io/angular-8-bazel-walkthrough-f7585bcaf282
About the compiler:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anphffaCZrQ

Comment: A better link is here https://angular.io/guide/bazel
What I'm most confused about is how it's still 'not stable' despite being Google's main build tool (afaik). What can actually go wrong?!